Настройка ssh в docker контейнере
Есть такой  Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu AS build

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y openssh-server

RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh 
COPY ./id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh
COPY ./id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN sed -i 's/\#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config 

Почему при запуске этого контейнера:
cp $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ./
docker build . -f Dockerfile -t develop:latest
docker run -it -p 2201:22 develop 

я не могу сразу зайти через ssh:
ssh -p 2201 root@127.0.0.1
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2201: Connection refused

нужно сначала в нем сделать рестарт ssh сервера:
root@14768b5d8a7c:/# /etc/init.d/ssh restart

Разве при запуске контейнера ssh-server не прочитает обновленный конфиг с PermitRootLogin yes?
Как сделать так что бы можно было сразу подцепляться по ssh?

контейнер не завершился, он запускается командой docker run -it -p 2201:22 develop

Впрочем, я в прошлом комментарии таки ошибся — по умолчанию запускается bash, и в общем-то нет никаких причин, почему должен был бы запуститься ssh-server

Если очень хочется, в интернетах предлагают прописать что-то вроде ENTRYPOINT service ssh start && bash, только вот запускать ssh внутри docker-контейнеров нафиг не надо, докер не для этого предназначен

Видимо вы путаете докер-контейнер с системой, на которой крутятся службы systemd. Чтобы что-то запустилось в контейнере, придется самому прописывать нужную команду и поддерживать процесс живым. Никакого service ssh start

Понял, спасибо.
